# How do I complete the "99 bottles of beer" puzzle (level 10)

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm on the bottles puzzle and being asked to use " to solve the next puzzle.

[image]

I don't have "
[image]

To get " I have to reach the other puzzles but I can't get off this island.

Does anybody have advice for what I should do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, I think you've found a bug.  Solving the "Wheels on the Bus" puzzle is what allows you to get to "99 bottles of beer" puzzle.  But based on the red text in your screenshot, you didn't finish solving the "Wheels on the Bus" puzzle.

When I try to recreate the situation you show, I get an error / warning message, and I'm prevented from getting to the "Delete me!" text.

[image: Stepping off this text now will leave no way to return.]

Working on it further, I was able to recreate your situation, by pasting the "wheels on the bus" (without first deleting it again), above the first line and above the last line.  I see no way to solve this except restarting the level by typing in `:level 10`.  (And you might consider sending the screenshot to the game author.)
[image: Cursor is stranded - cannot proceed, cannot retreat.]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @m_mlvx ! Could I just forward this thread?

Comment: Hi @Rubensz - sure, that's probably the easiest.  Cheers!